# Is it possible to download a big txt file containing many openings?

Tags: opening, programming, open-source, database

I am creating a small chess engine for a CS class, nothing serious, i need to read the openings from a txt file or any format, i can go to websites like chessgames.com and download individual games, but i was hoping to download big files containing many openings and so much data, especially on the dragon variation, but any data will do. So is there a place where i can get my hands on that kind of data?

---

Thanks for all the guys who answered, I upvoted all of them and accepted the one I think is the best, so grateful for all of you guys, i just want to add a site that i found today by mistake, [here](http://chess4real.com/robert-james-bobby-fischer-953-chess-games-to-download-1943-2008/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is a PGN file that contains several games. You can parse the game data and enter in the opening moves. A great resource is [PGN Mentor](http://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html#openings) where you can browse openings and download the appropriate PGNs.

Answer (score 3):

Is [Freeware: Chess Opening Book Txt](http://www.downloadcollection.com/freeware/chess-opening-book-txt.htm) what you are looking for?

There are a lot of opening also with evaluation. Sure you have to take care about the format which is used to store the information.

Answer (score 2):

Free chess opening books in Chessbase Book format (*.CTG) can be downloaded from http://www.hiarcs.com/chess-opening-book-free.htm

You can use it for a CS class project, but nothing commercial:

> Please note these books are free for you to download and use for your
>   personal use only. Under no circumstances are the books to be hosted
>   on another website without the prior express written permission of
>   Applied Computer Concepts Ltd.

Also useful will be [the CTG format unofficial specification](http://rybkaforum.net/cgi-bin/rybkaforum/topic_show.pl?tid=2319).