# Looking for pgn openings file

Tags: opening, engines

I am looking for a file containing several (>50 let's say) popular openings in PGN format.

The aim is to use it with [cutechess](http://cutechess.com/) to do engine testing on different opening scenarios.

Comment: So, you need an opening book in pgn format, that's it?

Comment: @lodebari: yes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you take a look at the **Silver Openings Suite** by [Albert Silver](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Albert+Silver). It's a hand-crafted set of 50 opening positions designed for balanced play, based on some non-trivial statistical analysis using [ChessBase](http://en.chessbase.com/post/test-your-engines-the-silver-openings-suite).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can download a pgn of ECO openings from [ChessVisor](http://www.chessvisor.com/v-aperturas.html). It contains 2014 variations of different openings.

The answers to the question [Is it possible to download a big txt file containing many openings](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4055/is-it-possible-to-download-a-big-txt-file-containing-many-openings?rq=1) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a suite of 2400 test positions in PGN format [available from the gaviota chess engine website](https://sites.google.com/site/gaviotachessengine/download). (look for "gaviota-starters.pgn.zip")

See also: The [Test Positions page on the Chess Programming Wiki](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Test-Positions), and this [collection of PGN and EPD openings posted to the CCC forum](http://www.talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=50619).